# The call is answered by another phone, audio file has to be played and second phone will hear the audio then audio file

Tags: java, android, eclipse

1. Dial a number that will given in code itself.
2. Once the call is answered by another phone, audio file has to be played so that the second phone will hear the audio.
3. After the audio file playing is complete, disconnect the line.

Comment: This is not generally supported.  It has also been asked here many times before, so you should expect this to eventually be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Have you code anything or you want us to code for you ?

Comment: I need a code for this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i complete the full code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final Context context = this;
MediaPlayer player;
//private Button btn;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     getInit();
    //btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    // add PhoneStateListener
    PhoneCallListener phoneCallListener = new PhoneCallListener();
    TelephonyManager telManager = (TelephonyManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telManager.listen(phoneCallListener,
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    // add button listener
    /*btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456"));
            startActivity(phoneCallIntent);

        }

    });*/

}

// monitor phone call states
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    String TAG = "LOGGING PHONE CALL";

    private boolean phoneCalling = false;

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            // phone ringing
            Log.i(TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // active
            Log.i(TAG, "OFFHOOK");

            phoneCalling = true;
            player.start();
        }

        // When the call ends launch the main activity again
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {

            Log.i(TAG, "IDLE");

            if (phoneCalling) {

                Log.i(TAG, "restart app");

                // restart app
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                getBaseContext().getPackageName());

                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

                phoneCalling = false;
                player.stop();
            }

        }
    }
}
 public void getInit() {
       player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a2);
       //player.prepareAsync();
       AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);  
       am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL); 
       am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
       //am.setMicrophoneMute(true);
     }
}
```

Place your mp3 file into raw folder for this code
like : player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a2);

AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.param.phonemusicincomecall"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_INCOMEING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<receiver android:name="com.example.phonecallapp.CallReceiver" android:enabled="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot this , for my project.It is not possible with android.Both android libraries , and device doesn't support this in the current scenario.